# Hanging captions with first line also indented

Tags: captions

I'm trying to match the formatting between a word document and latex document. In the word doc, captions have the caption label at the left margin, the label separator is effectively a tab character with a tab stop at 2cm, and then the caption text is formatted with a hanging indent at 2cm from the left margin.

This results in all of the blocks of caption text lining up down the page.
[image]

I can't work out how to replicate this in LaTeX.
[image]

The hang caption format gets close, but it sets the hanging indent relative to the caption label. Is there anyway to set an absolute value?

Comment: Easily done with the `caption` package. But we don't know what you're using, so I hesitate to answer.  Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

% Create a length
\newlength\caphang
% Set length as wanted
\setlength\caphang{2cm}

% caption.sty allows us to create our own format
% note: this version assumes the caption is only one paragraph!
\DeclareCaptionFormat{hangit}{%
  \hangindent=\caphang\hangafter=1%
  \makebox[\caphang][l]{#1#2}#3\par}

\captionsetup{format=hangit, singlelinecheck=no,
labelfont=sf, % if you want the label a different font, etc.
}

\def\dummytext{A figure or table caption mainly consists of three
  parts: the caption label, which says if this object is a ‘Figure’ or
  ‘Table’ and what number is associated with it, the caption text
  itself, which is normally a short description of contents, and the
  caption separator which separates the text from the label.}

\begin{document}

\dummytext

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{\dummytext}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{123}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{\dummytext}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  % \begin{tabular}{ll}
  %   one & two\\
  % \end{tabular}
    \caption{\dummytext}
\end{table}

\dummytext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This sets up a 1in margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\makebox[1in][l]{#1#2}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-1in}{#3}}

\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\captionof{figure}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]