# Properly indenting new lines in caption

Tags: tables, captions, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get a caption with manual line breaks, where the next lines indent on the left with the first one. By default the next lines are not indented at all, so I tried using a tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \rule{1cm}{1cm}
  \caption[Three figures]{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      Three figures\\
      a) Some very very very very very very very very very very long
         sentence that should wrap to the next line.\\
      b) Second\\
      c) Third      
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But in the result lines are not wrapped:

[image: Screenshot with the "a) …" line going past the right edge of the page]

I know the `p{width}` type of column allows wrapping lines, but the total width needs to be given manually, and the same goes for `tabularx`. This means that if the figure number bumps from `9` to `10`, the width of the rest of the caption will need to be re-adjusted manually.

> How can I get the following features?
>
> - Indentation so that all caption lines align with the first one
> - Word wrapping
> - Automatic calculation of word width

Comment: this might be helpful: [Hanging captions with first line also indented](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279117/579).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, `\usepackage{caption}` and putting \captionsetup{format=hang} inside the `figure` environment did the trick. Feel free to post this as an answer, or to mark as duplicate (I searched on this site but hadn't found that question).